# How do I edit/open a Smart Object in Photoshop using Python?

Tags: python, photoshop

```
SmartObjectLayer = psApp.ActiveDocument.ArtLayers("StarMap")
SmartObjectLayer.Kind = 17
psApp.Open(SmartObjectLayer)
```

Everything in my program is going good until I get to the `psApp.Open` part where I try opening a `SmartObject` layer, I was reading the documentation from here:

https://github.com/lohriialo/photoshop-scripting-python/blob/master/api_reference/photoshop_2020.py#L243

but I couldn't figure out how to open up the layer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Any updates on this!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to open the smart object, which then becomes the active document and you can iterate over the layers again and repeat, for example, if you have nested smart objects.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch, GetActiveObject, GetObject

app = GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application")
doc = app.Application.ActiveDocument
psDisplayNoDialogs = 3

for l in app.activeDocument.Layers:
    for layer in l.ArtLayers:
        if layer.Name == 'Name of your Smart Object':
            doc.activeLayer = layer
            ##this opens the smart object in photoshop
            app.ExecuteAction(app.StringIDToTypeID('placedLayerEditContents'))
```